# Importing module from a directory above current working directory

Tags: python, import, python-import

First of all, there are a bunch of solutions on stackoverflow regarding this but from the ones I tried none of them is working. I am working on a remote machine (linux). I am prototyping within the `dir-2/module_2.py` file using an ipython interpreter. Also I am trying to avoid using absolute paths as the absolute path in this remote machine is long and ugly, and I want my code to run on other machines upon download.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
/project-dir/
            -/dir-1/
                  -/__ init__.py
                  -/module_1.py
            -/dir-2/
                  -/__ init__.py
                  -/module_2.py
                  -/module_3.py
```

Now I want to import `module_1` from `module_2`. However the solution mentioned in this stackoverflow post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32767362/import-a-module-from-a-directory-package-one-level-up/32767774) of using

```
sys.path.append('../..')
import module_2
```

Does not work. I get the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module_1'`

Moreover, within the ipython interpreter things like `import .module_3` within `module_2` throws error:

> ```
> import .module_3
>        ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Isn't the dot operator supposed to work within the same directory as well. Overall I am quite confused by the importing mechanism. Any help with the initial problem is greatly appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Why it didn't work?

If you run the `module1.py` file and you want to import `module2` then you need something like

```py
sys.path.append("../dir-2")
```

If you use `sys.path.append("../..")` then the folder you added to the path is the folder containing `project-dir` and there is not `module2.py` file inside it.

---

The syntax `import .module_3` is for relative imports. if you tried to execute `module2.py` and it contains `import .module_3` it does not work because you are using `module2.py` as a script. To use relative imports you need to treat both `module2.py` and `module_3.py` as modules. That is, some other file imports module2 and module2 import something from module3 using this syntax.

### Suggestion on how you can proceed

One possible solution that solves both problems is property organizing the project and (optionally, ut a good idea) **packaging your library** (that is, make your code "installable"). Then, once your library is installed (in the virtual environment you are working) you don't need *hacky `sys.path` solutions*. You will be able to import your library from any folder.

Furthermore, don't treat your modules as scripts (don't run your modules). Use a separate python file as your "executable" (or entry point) and import everything you need from there. With this, relative imports in your `module*.py` files will work correctly and you don't get confused.

A **possible** directory structure could be

```
/project-dir/
            - apps/
                  - main.py
            - yourlib/
                  -/__ init__.py
                  -/dir-1/
                        -/__ init__.py
                        -/module_1.py
                  -/dir-2/
                        -/__ init__.py
                        -/module_2.py
                        -/module_3.py
```

Notice that the the `yourlib` folder as well as subfolders contain an `__init__.py` file. With this structure, you only run `main.py` (the name does not need to be `main.py`).

#### Case 1: You don't want to package your library

If you don't want to package your library, then you can add `sys.path.append("../")` in `main.py` to add "the `project-dir/` folder to the path. With that your `yourlib` library will be "importable" in `main.py`. You can do something like `from yourlib import module_2` and it will work correctly (and `module_2` can use relative imports). Alternatively, you can also directly put `main.py` in the `project-dir/` folder and you don't need to change `sys.path` at all, since `project-dir/` will be the "working directory" in that case.

Note that you can also have a `tests` folder inside `project-dir` and to run a test file you can do the same as you did to run `main.py`.

#### Case 2: You want to package your library

The previous solution already solves your problems, but going the extra mile adds some benefits, such as dependency management and no need to change `sys.path` no matter where you are. There are several options to package your library and I will show one option using [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) due to its simplicity.

After installing poetry, you can run the command below in a terminal to create a new project

```bash
poetry new mylib
```

This creates the following folder structure

```
mylib/
     - README.rst
     - mylib/
            - __init__.py
     - pyproject.toml
     - tests
```

You can then add the `apps` folder if you want, as well as subfolders inside `mylib/` (each with a `__init__.py` file).

The [`pyproject.toml`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/) file specifies the dependencies and project metadata. You can edit it by hand and/or use poetry to add new dependencies, such as

```bash
poetry add pandas
poetry add --dev mypy
```

to add `pandas` as a dependency and `mypy` as a development dependency, for instance. After that, you can run

```
poetry build
```

to create a virtual environment and install your library in it. You can activate the virtual environment with `poetry shell` and you will be able to import your library from anywhere. Note that you can change your library files without the need to run `poetry build` again.

At last, if you want to publish your library in PyPi for everyone to see you can use

```bash
poetry publish --username your_pypi_username --password _passowrd_
```

---

### TL; DR

Use an organized project structure with a clear place for the scripts you execute. Particularly, it is better if the script you execute is outside the folder with your modules. Also, don't run a module as a script (otherwise you can't use relative imports).

Comment: Thank you for this extremely thorough answer. Wish I could've upvoted it twice. I was just looking for something like this. In fact I was looking into how I can package my library. I actually needed to package my library anyway in the near future, I will just do it now.

Comment: Btw, since you are already knowledgeable, could you please tell me if I can make pip installable packages using poetry? I need to package my algorithm to be pip installable by anyone. If you mention where I should start looking first that would help me not  randomly look all over the place! Thanks again!

Comment: pip installs libraries from [PyPi](https://pypi.org/), which means that the procedure I described is all you need. It does not matter if poetry was used, of if you manually wrote `setup.py` using distutils, or if you used any of the other available tools not mentioned here. You will be able to install your library from Pypi with just `pip install yourlibrary`. I have already published two libraries this way.

Comment: hi, nice answer. what about the need for __init__.py . Isn't the case that pyhton3 does not need that file in order to recognize a directory as a package ? thanks

Comment: It's still a good idea to add it, unless you have a reason not too. See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139786/is-init-py-not-required-for-packages-in-python-3-3](this question).