# Erroneous red lines and "Unresolved reference" errors in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, python-import

I have the following folder structure:

```
project/
├── main.py
├── package/
    ├── __init__.py
    └── module.py
    └── test.py
```

In module.py, I have a function func1.

In test.py, I have the following code:

```
 from module import func1
```

PyCharm shows me red lines under "module" and under "func1", claiming "Unresolved reference module" and "Unresolved reference func1". However, when I run the code with Python3, it runs fine.

How can I avoid these red lines?

Comment: You should tell PyCharm where are the different "root" directories of your project. On left side, where you have the files, go to your project directory, select, and right click, then "mark directory as...", and then "source root". Note: you may have multiple source root (test, documentation, etc.)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi works like a (py)charm. Thanks

Comment: Another more general way (not specific to PyCharm) is to properly package your library code. Then you install it in a virtual environment. With this you can import your library from anywhere. I have answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64107888/importing-module-from-a-directory-above-current-working-directory) with *one* way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try invalidating your caches and restarting IDEA (File > Invalidate Cache). Wait for IDEA to re-index your project (Status indicator on lower right status bar). The caches will sometimes become corrupted. This is most likely to occur upon reorganizing a project as you mentioned you did.