# Relative imports in python and pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pyinstaller

I have following project structure and i'm using PyCharm.

> - Project/
>
>   - subproject1/
>
>     - main.py
>     - modules/
>
>       - 1.py
>       - __init__.py
>   - subproject2/
>
>     - main.py
>     - modules/
>   - subproject3/
>
>     - __init__.py
>     - file.py

I need in `Project/subproject/modules/1.py` a class from `Project/subproject3/file.py`. I tried it with `from ...subproject3.file import class1`, but then i get the error `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`. Next i tried the import `from subproject3.file import class1`, and that work's, but i don't know why. My working directory in PyCharm is in `Project/` but i tried to create a Python application with pyinstaller and that worked also for me and a received no error message. Why does my file 1.py knows from subproject3 and i can import it that way?

Thank you!!

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64110410/1102805).

Comment: Thank you for this link! It's a very good answer and cleared a few of my irritations.But why i get no error when i import from Project/subproject3/file with the command ``from subproject3.file import class1``?? Why does this works?

Comment: If the current working directory is `Project` or if the `Project` folder is added to `sys.path` then importing `subproject3` works because it is understood as a package, since it has a `__init__.py` file inside it. That is what tells python to treat  `subproject3` as a package. On the other hand, importing `subproject1` or `subproject2` won't work since they are not packages, just regular folders. Add a `__init__.py` file inside them and you will be able to import from them.

Comment: Okay thanks. I saw that in ``sys.path`` the ``Project`` folder is included in PyCharm. How i can know if the ``Project`` folder is included when i create a Python Application with pyinstaller? And when i try to execute the ``main.py`` in ``subproject1`` in the console the ``Project`` folder is not included and i don´t can fix it with adding the ``Project`` path to ``sys.path``.